# Display the number and percentage of missing for continuous and categorical variables in a table using the gtsummary package

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am attempting to display the number and percentage of missing for continuous and categorical variables in a table using the `gtsummary` package. I think there is a way to do this for continuous variables but not for categorical variables. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know this can be done with other packages but I would like to do this with the `gtsummary` package.

```
library("reprex")
library("tibble")
library("tidyverse")
library("hesim")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'hesim'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     expand
library("gtsummary")

set.seed(124)
n=42233
simdata <- tibble(

  Age = ifelse(rbinom(n, size=1, prob=0.2)==0, rnorm(n, mean=68, sd=11),
               NA_real_),
  
  Race = factor(ifelse(rbinom(n, size=1, prob=0.1)==0,hesim::rcat(n, cbind(0.724, 0.19, 0.083)),
                       NA_character_),
                levels = c(1,2,3),
                labels = c("White","Black","Other"))
)


simdata %>% 
  tbl_summary(missing = "no", 
            type = list(
              all_continuous() ~ "continuous2"),
            statistic = list(
              all_continuous() ~ c("{mean} ({sd})",
                                   "{N_miss} ({p_miss}%)"),
              
              all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)")) %>%
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**") %>%
  add_stat_label(location = "row") %>%
  modify_spanning_header(starts_with("stat_") ~ "Table 1") %>% 
  bold_labels()
```

[image]

I am trying to get something like the following.
[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including the code you have tried so far and a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example with each post. I think the easiest way to add this is to create a new variable that indicates if the variable of interest is missing or not. Place the new variable after the original variable it's associated with.  https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/1251#issuecomment-1133492768

Comment: Thanks. I just added the reproducible code above. I wonder if there is a code equivalent to `continuous2` for categorical variable. Thank you both

Answer (score 1):

The default is number of missings in `gtsummary`. You can make factor variables missing a real level, then they are given as percentage by default.

```
# get minimal data
data(mtcars)

# create missing data, pick categorical variable
library(missMethods)
cars_missing <- delete_MCAR(mtcars[,c(1,11)], 0.3)
cars_missing$carb_factor <- as_factor(cars_missing$carb)
as_tibble(cars_missing)

# A tibble: 32 × 3
     mpg  carb carb_factor
   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>      
 1  21       4 4          
 2  NA       4 4          
 3  22.8     1 1          
 4  NA      NA NA         
 5  18.7     2 2          
 6  18.1     1 1          
 7  NA       4 4          
 8  24.4    NA NA         
 9  22.8     2 2          
10  19.2    NA NA         
# … with 22 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

# Make categorical missings a real category
library(tidyverse)
cars_missing <- cars_missing %>% 
  mutate(carb_factor = factor(carb_factor) %>% forcats::fct_explicit_na(na_level = "Unknown"))

# gtsummary
library(gtsummary)
tbl_summary(cars_missing)
```

[image]